# display subject-predicate-object as graph using java

Tags: java, eclipse, nlp

I'm trying to to display subject-predicate-object as a graph by using Java, without duplicates.
But I don't know how to do that.

I'm trying to display each sentence along with a SVO graph, but I'm not getting the graph.
I'm able to extract the sentences along with triplets.

I need more references on that matter.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Stanford parser, which shows the graph of a sentence?

I think you can pass the triplet to parser and get graph.